# WPF with EntityFramework error

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I've got a basic Window that looks like this:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="ShootingRangeClient.Shooters"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Shooters" 
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="23" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource SearchTextBox}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1"/>
        <DataGrid Name="ShootersDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" />        
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

and the codebehind part:

```
namespace ShootingRangeClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Shooters.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Shooters
    {
        public SRDBEntities db;

        public Shooters()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            db = new SRDBEntities();
            List<Shooters> sh = db.Shooters.Select(it => it).ToList();

            ShootersDataGrid.ItemsSource = sh;
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as it gets to this part:

```
db.Shooters.Select(it => it)
```

i receive the following exception:

```
The component 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Shooters_66339B43C72C5E730A746B2CE9B8CA7B6D2B66B2BC9DAE1C3BFCCD0C04B1CEC1' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/ShootingRangeClient;component/shooters.xaml'.
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: How does your Shooters class look like?

Comment: Try to use regualr window instead of MetroWindow. Because I think this is not an error generated by entity framework, but it might be an error from CustomControl.

Comment: Also I think your Shooters class should Inherit from MetroWindow or Window.

Comment: @Vishal Doesn;t it already do that if it's a partial class?

Comment: Oh God, I should have some sleep. Issue resolved, the problem was the following:
I've had a Window named Shooters (and class Shooters for it) AND entity Shooters (and a class for it). Don't know how they interacted with each other since both were autogenerated and both were partial classes, but the result has been as you've seen.
Fixed by renaming Window into ShootersWindow. Works like a charm now, thanks a lot for your leading questions. =-)

Comment: @DavidG I am sorry. I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Get into the habit of naming things differently from standard objects as well providing unique names for all generated classes. Just because one can resolve it by namespacing doesn't mean its best. As you have seen machines as well as people have a difficult time reading the original authors intent/mind.

The same can be said for test data, by making sure there are no clone's within the data it might help debug or explain data going forward..